# DateTime format in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

I have the following and I get the time back but I want to add hours to it.  I'm not having luck. I have tried SimpleDateTime but cannot seem to get the syntax correct.

```
package com.sayitfast.service;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


public class TimeData {
    private String time;
    private Long milliseconds_since_epoch;
    private String date;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TimeData" + "time=" + time + ", milliseconds_since_epoch="
                + milliseconds_since_epoch + ", date=" + date;
    }

    public void TimeData() {

    }

    public void mytimdData() throws IOException {
        String webPage = "http://time.jsontest.com";

        InputStream is = nw URL(webPage).openStream();
        final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TimeData td = gson.fromJson(reader, TimeData.class);

        System.out.println(td.time);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show some example code that tries to add hours? You current code example doesn't, it just reads from a JSON source... You could also add a sample of the JSON data.

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the problem? What do you mean by adding hours? Do you mean you have a time of day like "9:56 pm" and you want to add for example 6 hours to it?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead you may use `DateTimeFormatter` and/or `Instant` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to add

```
 String webPage = "http://time.jsontest.com";

            InputStream is = new URL(webPage).openStream();
            final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            TimeData td = gson.fromJson(reader, TimeData.class);

            System.out.println(td.toString());
            
            System.out.println(td.getTime());
            DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
            Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(td.getTime());
            
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
           Date dates = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println(dates);
```

Here I have increased the time to 1hr. This is an example you can change as per your requirement

Also, you can use `Date incrementedDate = DateUtils.addHour(date, 1);` instead of `Calender`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API to the [rich set of modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and do it as follows (includes demo of some custom formats as well):

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        // Custom formats
        DateTimeFormatter formatter24Hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter12Hour = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");

        // Get the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
        long epochMilli = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
        System.out.println("The number of milliseconds from the epoch is " + epochMilli);
        System.out.println();

        // Get Instant from the number of milliseconds from the epoch
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli);

        // Get LocalDateTime from Instant
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());// Use the zone as per your requirement
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println("Date-time in your time-zone: " + ldt);
        System.out.println("Time in your time-zone: " + ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
        System.out.println("Time in your time-zone: " + ldt.format(formatter24Hour));
        System.out.println("Time in your time-zone: " + ldt.format(formatter12Hour));
        System.out.println();

        // Add some hours e.g. 2 hours to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime newDateTime = ldt.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println("Date-time in your time-zone after 2 hours: " + newDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The number of milliseconds from the epoch is 1593532251048

Date-time in your time-zone: 2020-06-30T16:50:51.048
Time in your time-zone: 16:50:51.048
Time in your time-zone: 16:50:51
Time in your time-zone: 04:50:51 pm

Date-time in your time-zone after 2 hours: 2020-06-30T18:50:51.048
```

Comment: Excellent and thank you... I really like the simplicity of this answer.

Comment: It works (on my Java 11). I more or less suspect that it works due to a bug in java.time, though, since I cannot read from the documentation that `SSS` should be able to parse only two decimals, and since I couldn’t get the corresponding to work with `LocalTime`.

Comment: My suggestion today is to stick to the `ZonedDateTime` you got. I see no point in converting to `LocalDateTime` since the `ZonedDateTime` can be formatted in the same (and more) ways, and you can add hours to it in the same way. Bonus: the latter will also work correctly across transitions from and to summer time (DST) in the time zone in question.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable feedback.

Comment: @OleV.V. - I didn't understand your first comment, `It works (on my Java 11) ....` w.r.t. this Q/A.

Comment: There may be nothing to understand. I tried in Java 11, and it worked. Exactly because the docs don’t seem to say it works, I didn’t want to guarantee that it would work on all other Java versions, so I though the version might be worth mentioning. BTW I tried on [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), it worked too. My guess until someone knows better is it works on all versions.